# Git push command getting stuck after 100%

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys, git-push

I am on branch **fsp** .I have used Following commands:

```
git pull origin master

git add .

git commit -m "message"
```

and then

```
abc@abc689:~/Workspace2/M-Egal(fsp)$ git push origin fsp
Counting objects: 103, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (87/87), done.
Writing objects: 100% (103/103), 20.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 103 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

After this it is not responding. It is stuck at this point can anyone help ?
I have ssh connection with account and have used these steps several time before also.

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.7.4

Comment: It happened to me in heavy memory LFS.

Comment: @rajanaDeepak what exactly you do to solve this ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue has been resolved after I switched the Internet connection from local cafe's Wi-Fi to mobile data